# msys64, mingw: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: mingw, msys

I'm trying to build unix project using msys and mingw on Windows.

When I try to make my project, I get an error:

```
C:\msys64\usr\share\bash-completion\completions\make: line 93: syntax error near unexpected token `('
C:\msys64\usr\share\bash-completion\completions\make: line 93: `        --assume-new|-!(-*)[foW])'
```

What can cause this error?

Comment: Please post the code causing the error. Specifically: what is on line 93 of the Makefile (and the lines around it)?